# Hosting a Laravel App on a Virtual Server

Tags: laravel, hosting, shared-hosting

Forgive me if this would have been better placed somewhere else on the stackexchange network but I have seen a few Laravel questions being asked here so thought it would be OK.

Anyways...

I have a Laravel app which I want to get online and found some hosting here: https://www.server4you.net/virtual-server

The pricing is really good and there is root / SSH access. As I dont know if my web app will be a financial success I dont wanna go all out on a  dedicated server but also don't mind migrating it at a later date (I know this will be a pain!)

I have seen a few people online recommend against using a VPS / shared server for a laravel app...my question is why?

If the servers can perform as advertised then this should be good?

I have never bought a vps or uploaded my own Laravel project to a server before so I feel like I should ask these questions now before I realise I have shot myself in the foot somehow way down the line...

Cheers!

Comment: a vps is more than enough for a starting project. I have several Laravel projects running on vps'.

Comment: Of course that VPS is enough for your project. A lot of people may use your app and VPS will be dealing with it easily. Of course vps performance also depends on your app architecture. You may even have more than one app on your VPS.

Comment: wow cool! ok...thanks I really appreciate it guys!